# Add xap file in sd card on windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, sd-card

I created a sample app in windows phone 8,now i want to add my xap file into  windows phone  device,for that i copied xap file into sd card,but in windows device,there is no file exists in sdcard in store tile,
Any suggestions?

Comment: is the device developer unlocked?

Comment: how to find the device developer is locked r unlocked?

Comment: You will have manually unlocked the device if it is. If you try and deploy to it from visual studio it will tell you if it's locked. The same with the "Application Deployment" tool.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot install a xap file into phone like this.

there are two ways to install an app one is by downloading it from app store and other one is by installing app from visual studio on a developer unlocked device.